# Node.js - Can't render/send something from middleware

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, post, middleware

I have a express server runnnig on the port 8082. After accessing the route "/" as GET it renders the index.html file, then I send its form to "/" as POST using the app.js script. This route has a middleware called "validate1" that checks if the header "x-client" is equals "student" in order to control this route access.

The problem is that when the header "x-client" is not equals "student", and the "validate1" middleware ends up in the "else", I just can't render or send anything as response. The node.js prints my "here" but it doesn't run its next "res.send()" line.

At the "/travel" route I have pretty much the same middleware working perfectly, but there I am using the GET method and none jquery.

UPDATE: I figured out my response is being printed in my browser console because of my ".then()" at the jquery POST function in "app.js", but even deleting it the response  is never displayed at the page.

index.html

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"><!-- rota no css-->
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        Nome:<input name="nome" type="text" id="nome">
        <br>
        Sobrenome:<input name="sobrenome" type="text" id="sobrenome">
        <button>Send data</button>
    </form>

</body>

<script src="./app.js"></script>
</html>
```

app.js

```
$("button").on("click", (event) => {
    $("button").attr("disabled","disabled")
    const nome = $("#nome").val().trim()
    const sobrenome = $("#sobrenome").val().trim()

    const user = {
        nome,
        sobrenome
    }

    $.ajax({
        url:"/",
        method:"POST",
        data:user,
        headers:{
            "x-client":"student",
            "x-class":500
        }
    }).then((resposta) => {
        console.log(resposta)
    }).catch((erro) => {
        console.log("Error:" + erro)
    })
})
```

routing.js

```
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")entre windows e mac

const router = express.Router()

router.get("/",(req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"../views/index.html"))
})

//not working route
const validate1 = (req,res,next) => {
    const access = req.headers["x-client"]
    if(access === "student2"){
        next()
    }
    else{
        console.log("here")//it runs!
        res.send("You don't have access to it!")//it doesn't run!
    }
}

router.post("/", validate1 ,(req,res) => {
    const user = {
        nome:req.body.nome,
        sobrenome: req.body.sobrenome
    }

    res.json(user)
})

//working route

const validate2 = (req,res,next) => {
    const access = false
    if(access){
        next()
    }
    else{
        res.send("You don't have access to it!")  
    }
}

router.get("/travel",validate2,(req,res) => {
    res.send("Travel!")   
})
```

Actually I don't get any error, but instead receiving the message I was supposed my form button just gets disabled and nothing happens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a `POST` HTTP call, whereas you are using `router.get` in your `routing.js` file.

Can you change your code to something like this:

```
router.post("/", validate1 ,(req,res) => {
    const user = {
        nome:req.body.nome,
        sobrenome: req.body.sobrenome
    }

    res.json(user)
})
```

Make the following changes to app.js to display the reponse message in index.html

```
$("button").on("click", (event) => {
    $("button").attr("disabled","disabled")
    const nome = $("#nome").val().trim()
    const sobrenome = $("#sobrenome").val().trim()

    const user = {
        nome,
        sobrenome
    }

    $.ajax({
        url:"/",
        method:"POST",
        data:user,
        headers:{
            "x-client":"student",
            "x-class":500
        }
    }).then((resposta) => {
        console.log(resposta)
        $('body').append(resposta);
    }).catch((erro) => {
        console.log("Error:" + erro)
    })
})
```

Comment: Did you see the console window of the browser. Did you see any message being printed there.

Comment: Actually I've changed to GET in order to make some tests, I will update my question, thanks for the observation. The problem persists even this route being a POST one. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, in fact I just did! It is ebeing displayed at the console of the browser. It is because of the ".then" I suppose, but I want to make it reach the page.

Comment: I have edited the answer, can you please try with the changes.

Comment: Now I have the answer displayed on my page, right under the form. My goal was to display it in a blank page which would be the "res.send()" effect, but it is already helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Cool @DenisOliveira. If this had helped you out please consider accepting this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your page is refreshing? Since the form element itself may be performing a submission, you might try including `event.preventDefault()` at the top of your click handler. This would explain why your server's else clause is running, but no message is seen client-side.

Comment: I've updated my question, the response is just not going to the place it should, the main page. It goes to the console of the browser. I adeed this line to my code and it seems nothing changed. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for thanking me anyway! That does seem to be a head-scratcher...

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but maybe the post expect to json 
so try to send

```
res.send({msg:'some msg'});
```

or set the content-type header to 'text'

Comment: I just tried res.send({msg:'some msg'}) and it keeps the same, nothing happens.
I already also tried "res.json()" and"res.redirect()" but it seems to be ignored.

The header system is working fine, the code correctly ends up in the right " f "scope", it even prints my "here" console.log().

Thank you.